# Bug while cross compiling from Windows to Linux?

Tags: debugging, go

When cross-compiling my code from Win10 to Linux, the following code stopped using rows.next

```
    executed rows.Next()

    rows, err := DB.Query("SELECT * FROM `machines`")
    erh.Check(err)

    newUsers := make(map[string]User, count)
    defer erh.Check(rows.Close())    
    for rows.Next() {
        //tu is temp user
        tu := User{}
        err := rows.Scan(&tu.Id, &tu.Name, &tu.Apikey, &tu.Ip, &tu.Machine, &tu.State, &tu.DbAvailable)
        erh.Check(err)
        log.Println(tu)
        newUsers[tu.Apikey] = tu
    }
```

When I placed the defer under rows.Next the rows.next code was executed

```
rows, err := DB.Query("SELECT * FROM `machines`")
erh.Check(err)

newUsers := make(map[string]User, count)

for rows.Next() {
    //tu is temp user
    tu := User{}
    err := rows.Scan(&tu.Id, &tu.Name, &tu.Apikey, &tu.Ip, &tu.Machine, &tu.State, &tu.DbAvailable)
    erh.Check(err)
    log.Println(tu)
    newUsers[tu.Apikey] = tu
}
defer erh.Check(rows.Close())
```

Can someone confirm this is a bug, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: i use a mysql database @TheHippo

Comment: Why do you think the problem is related with crross-compiling? In what condition it works ? When compiled from Linux and running on same machine as when it doesn’t works?

Comment: @mgagnon when i run the test files on my local windows machine everything works, when i compile it for linux and run it on the server it stops working. but putting the defer lower in the code makes the code work again

Comment: Ha ok, good to know. So the issue is more when running on linux versus in windows than cross-compiling versus native compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how this could work on Linux, it shouldn't. This line:

```
    defer erh.Check(rows.Close())
```

Will execute `rows.Close()` *immediately*, hold the return value, then defer *only* the call to `erh.Check`. That's how defer works - arguments are evaluated immediately. [From the docs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements):

> Each time a "defer" statement executes, the function value and parameters to the call are evaluated as usual and saved anew but the actual function is not invoked.

If you want to use a construct like this, it would have to be within a closure, something like:

```
defer func() {
    erh.Check(rows.Close())
}()
```

So that there are no arguments to evaluate at the time of `defer`.

Comment: withouth err.Check the behaviour is the same, in go 1.9 the code

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. According to your post, "when I placed the defer under rows.Next the rows.next code was executed," which is consistent with the above issue.

Comment: i meant that when it was defer rows.Close() it also did not work, even though that worked when to code was written with go 1.9

Comment: Are you working with a different version of Go now? There have been no changes I'm aware of that would make any difference. If you're having an issue with different code, consider updating your question or opening a new question.